# select a contour from candidate contours list

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

in  opencv  contour detection i am getting multiple contours near about to each other.  in this image i have to select a contour from each group of closest contours. 
how can i select a contour per group.
 i know about dilate image , and already done , but it not worked well for me.
see attached image has four contours. i need to select two from them , one from each group.
how can achieve that.[image: select a contours from group of possibles]

Comment: What about iterating over all of your contours and only selecting contours that do not have their centers inside an already selected contour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Source image [image: like this] & You want to Find the Board [image: from the Image]. You can follow this pseudo code. You can implement the same in c++ easily.
Note that here I've used the CV_RETR_EXTERNAL parameter to retrieve the outermost contours.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> Img_Result_Bgr = Img_Source_Bgr.Clone();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Org_Gray = Img_Source_Bgr.Convert<Gray, byte>();
Img_Org_Gray = Img_Org_Gray.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(250), new Gray(255));

#region Finding Contours
using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //allocate storage for contour approximation
    for (Contour<Point> contours = Img_Org_Gray.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
    {
        Contour<Point> contours_Approximated = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.005,storage);
        if (contours.Area > 10) //only consider contours with area greater than 100
        {
            Img_Result_Bgr.Draw(contours_Approximated, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
        }
    }
#endregion
imageBox1.Image = Img_Result_Bgr;
```

Comment: thanks i will try in few minutes..and reply..while i am in between to apply above approach by @Random-I-Am .